# Towing Car with all wheels on the ground

Tags: nissan, towing, sunny

I bought my Nissan Sunny automatic car about a year ago. So far, I have towed it three times with all four wheels on the ground, about 40 km in the aggregate. I didn’t know that it was bad for the transition until recently. But my car is still okay and I have noticed nothing wrong with it. My question is how may I know whether anything is damaged in my car’s engine or not? Is it certain that anything is damaged? If so  should I take it to a mechanic?  Thank you,

Comment: Increased wear could have occurred to the transmission.  No damage will have been caused to the engine.

Answer (score 2):

They make wheels that bolt on in place of the drive wheels that have bearings in them so they spin independent of the cars transmission and drive axles.  We used them to tow our race cars to the track before we could build a decent trailer.  Check Summit racing, they might have them....you WILL eventually kill your transmission if you continue to spin it like that.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a manual and you had it in neutral when it was towed, then, normally, no problem, depending on **why** it needed to be towed.

If it was an automatic, then that may be a different story - some automatics state that the driving wheels must be lifted to be towed, others say that a maximum distance of 10 or 15 miles is allowable.

Comment: Actually it is automatic